# Dynamic height adjustment

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I have two boxes like:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="content">Here goes content 1.</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="content">Here goes content 2.</div>
</div>


.content {height:150px;width:65px;}
```

Now it can be that the text of content 1 doesn't fit the height of 150px. The div stretches.
How can I achieve that the class changes the height so that the second content will have the same height as content 1?

Comment: Can you use JQuery or do you have to rely on pure javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not feel too elegant, but it works (at least in FF, Chrome and Safari for Mac, as I did not have the time to test it in IE):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
       var minHeight = 150;
       var contentDivs = [];
       var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

       // find the content div with the tallest height
       for (var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
          var div = divs[i];
          if (div.className == "content") {
             minHeight = Math.max(minHeight, div.offsetHeight);
             contentDivs.push(div);
          }
       }

       // set the content divs' height to the tallest height
       for (var j=0; j < contentDivs.length; j++) {
          var contentDiv = contentDivs[j];
          contentDiv.style.height = minHeight + "px";
       }
   }
</script>

.content {width:65px;}
```

Don't forget to remove the `height:150px` from your css or the height of the elements won't be adjusted.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your post. I'll see what I can do with it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Put them inside a parent DIV and make the height auto for the second one.

Comment: Hi, this would be a great idea, but unfortunately I can't change any html-structure because of the structure itselves.